# How to create a button with image in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to create a button with cancel option(image).
Please have a look image.
Cancel or button both have different click option. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UK28.png)How I can achieve this.

Comment: Yes but I want two event on cancel click and button text click. How I can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple StackLayout with horizontal orientation and use Tap Gesture for image and label to achieve your target.

 Hope this may solve your issue.

Comment: Yes but I want two event on cancel click and button text click. How I can do that

Comment: @Parmendra if you will use tap gesture for image and for label then it will have two different events only, one for cancel image click and one for label text click.Let me know if you want any more explanation

Answer (score 0):

The Button has an image property you can define in xaml. Just add the name of your image and make sure it exists in the resources / drawable folders

Comment: Yes but I want two event on cancel click and button text click. How I can do that

Comment: It is common sense for a button to be a single GUI Item causing one defined action when being clicked. No one would expect a button to cause different actions depending on where it was clicked.

However what you want to do are actually two buttons which look as one.
So create a background element, as MShah already proposed, add one button with an image and another text button. Then let each button press do what you want it do do and adjust the button visuals (color, border, etc) to look as if they would be one thing.